# error while running apt-get update probably incorrect release file causing apt-get update to fail

Tags: repository, apt-get, software-update

I've been using *elementary OS 0.3 Freya (64-bit)* built on *Ubuntu 14.04*

When I tried to open **Software Updater** its showing **Failed to download repository information**
and when I tried to run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

this is what it prints:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'restricted/source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I donno whats the problem and I cann't find a solution for this while I googled it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read on the issue, one of the repositories has failed.  Maybe try removing them one at a time and see if you can find the offending one.

Edit the ppa's and change freya to trusty.  Not sure if this is the ideal solution, but it fixes it.

Comment: Here is an article that backs up my theory: http://itsfoss.com/failed-to-download-repository-information-ubuntu-13-04/

Answer (score 0):

I removed Chrome download/update from the download list and changed the Ubuntu Software Settings in column 1 to Download from main server. It did the download and update this way.